# Does adding milk to cereal make it harder for our body to absorb the vitamins and minerals from the cereal?

Tags: digestive-system, milk, digestion

I add about 3/4 cups of Blue Diamond almond milk (unsweetened) every morning to a single serving of Cheerios. The milk contains filtered water, and I read that drinking water with food at the same time makes it harder for the small intestine to absorb the nutrients from the food. Has this been verified?

Comment: This topic is more appropriate for http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do not migrate this to skeptics please. You've read it _where_? How does this apply when you're eating say a tomato, most of which consists of water. As do 90% of all foods you eat.

Comment: And by which way should water hinder the absorption?

Answer (score 1):

Overall, no it doesn't. Cereal is made in a way that it's expected consumers will consume it with milk. Here's a list of some important fortifications added to cereal and milk effects on absorption.

**Riboflavin**: No. Affected most strongly by light.

**Iron**: Yes. Calcium can affect absorption. Milk causing a deficiency is rare unless it is being used as a breast milk substitute in babies.

**Thiamin**: No. Unless you are drinking alcohol with your cereal.

**Folic acid**: Milk is a source of this!

Comment: What about zinc?